# How can i fix the error "illegal target for annotation" in python?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, and this program worked fine, but suddenly i got a red line from the : at line 33 to the end of the program, with the error "illegal target for annotation". How could i fix this?

```
import turtle
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal
import sys
account_1_name = "John Smith"
account_1_balance = "67.58"
account_1_vault_balance = "200.00"
style = ('Calibri', 30)
password = input("What is your password?")
if password == "Cryptic":
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.bgcolor("green")
    turtle.write("Access Granted.", font=style)
    turtle.done()
    prompt = input("""
    Welcome to Bank Network.

    Hello, %s
    Your balance is $%s
    Your savings account balance is $%s.

    type transfer to transfer money to savings section.      
    type deposit to deposit a check.""" % (account_1_name, account_1_balance , account_1_vault_balance))
    if prompt == "deposit":
            print("deposit system is down right now. Please try again later.")
            sys.exit(0)
    if prompt == "transfer":
        transfer_amount = input("How much do you want to transfer?")
        transfer_prompt = input("""
        are you sure you want to transfer money to your savings section?
        type cancel to cancel.
        type confirm to transfer"""
    if transfer_amount > account_1_balance:
        print("Not enough balance.")
    if transfer_amount < account_1_balance:
        print("Ok. Money transfered.")
        balance_post_transfer = Decimal(account_1_balance) - Decimal(transfer_amount)
        account_1_vault_balance_post_transfer = Decimal(account_1_vault_balance) + Decimal(transfer_amount)
        print("Your balance is now $%s and your savings account balance is $%s" % (balance_post_transfer, account_1_vault_balance_post_transfer))
if password != ("Cryptic"):
    turtle.hideturtle()
    print("access denied.")
    turtle.bgcolor("red")
    turtle.write("access denied.", font=style)
    turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From line 29 to 32, you have:

```
transfer_prompt = input("""
    are you sure you want to transfer money to your savings section?
    type cancel to cancel.
    type confirm to transfer"""
```

You didn't close the input. That is the reason of your error. Replace those lines by:

```
transfer_prompt = input("""
    are you sure you want to transfer money to your savings section?
    type cancel to cancel.
    type confirm to transfer""")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this false error if you have a ':' at the end of a line of code where it isn't supposed to be. :)

if **name** == '**main**':
write_sequence(filename='C:\Python\File_IO\recaman.txt', num=0)

if it's this the error shows up.  I got in the habit of throwing this at the end of lines if it looked like some action is to be taken.
if **name** == '**main**':
write_sequence(filename='C:\Python\File_IO\recaman.txt', num=0)**:**